# swift SubClass and Casting

Tags: casting, swift, subclass

this is the test I made:
I defined 2 classes:

```
class Test1 {
    var p1:String? = "p1"
    init(){
       println("init test1")
    }
}

class Test2: Test1 {
    init() {
        super.init()
        p1 = "p2"
        println("init test2")
    }

}
```

then I create an instance of Test2

```
let x = Test2()
```

and I would to check if Test2 is a subClass of Test2

```
if x is Test1 {
    println("ok")
}else{
    println("no")
}
```

but I have a build error: *Test1 is not a subType of Test2*

where am I wrong?

I tried, without success, also this:

```
if let y = x as? Test1 {
    println("ok")
}else{
    println("no")
}
```

Comment: I found a way to handle this

   **let x:AnyObject = Test2()**

then the casting wokrs

does anybody explain deeper the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to / can't change the code around your context, you can cast upwards and then do a downcast test on a single line:

```
if x as Any is Test1 {
    println("ok")
}else{
    println("no")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `is`, `as` and `as?` operators are used "downwards" only. That is, if you have an instance typed as `Test1`, you can check if it possible to downcast it to `Test2` with `is`.

If you want to check if an instance of `Test2` is a subclass of any particular class you use `isKindOfClass()`. However, this will only work for classes that are in `NSObject`'s class hierarchy.

```
let x = Test2() 
if x.isKindOfClass(Test1) {
    println("ok")
} else {
    println("no")
}
```

Comment: This works only for objective c objects, not for swift native objects

Comment: (in the second case, you'll receive a "Test2 does not have a member named 'isKindOfClass'"

Comment: I see the problem. This only works for classes that are in the `NSObject` class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Cezar, is works only "downwards".
However, you can rewrite your statement like this:

```
    var x: AnyObject = Test2()

    if x is Test1 {
        println("ok")
    }else{
        println("no")
    }
```

Declare x as Anyobject, so you can test it for conformance to any object type.
This will print ok

Comment: We wrote it at the same time (53 vs 54 min ago ;-) and I explained the reason, as you requested

Comment: ahjahajaajha :) I'm reading it paying attention on it ;) thanks